# API not returning data

Tags: php, symfony4, api-platform.com

Am working on API platform framework for searching something, am getting empty objects as reply but the count of array of objects is correct.

Entity Annotation:-

```
    @ApiResource(
    attributes={
      "order"={"Date": "DESC", "title": "ASC"},
       "normalization_context"={"groups"={"student.read"}, 
     "enable_max_depth"=true},
    },
    normalizationContext={
       "groups"={"student.read"}
    },
    collectionOperations={
      "get",
      "post",
      "get_list_students"={
           "route_name"="api_student_list",
           "normalization_context"={"groups"={"student.read"}}
       },
    },
    denormalizationContext={
       "groups"={"student.write"}
    },
  )
```

i have a controller to fetch the students from database am specifying the annotation as follows:-

Controller Annotation:-

```
 @Route(
      path="/api/student/list",
     name="api_student_list",
     methods={"GET"},
     defaults={
       "_api_collection_operation_name"="get_list_students",
       "_api_normalization_context"={"api_sub_level"=true},
       "_api_swagger_context"={
           "tags"={"student"},
           "summary"="Retrieve a list of students",
           "parameters" = {
               {
                   "name" = "teacher_id",
                   "required" = false,
                   "type" = "string",
                   "in" = "query"
               },
               {
                   "name" = "school_id",
                   "required" = false,
                   "type" = "string",
                   "in" = "query"
               },
               {
                   "name" = "search_term",
                   "required" = false,
                   "type" = "string",
                   "in" = "query"
               },
               {
                   "name" = "order",
                   "required" = false,
                  "type" = "string",
                  "in" = "query",
                  "enum" = { "studentname" },
                   "description" = "studentname"
               },
               {
                   "name" = "direction",
                   "required" = false,
                  "type" = "string",
                   "in" = "query",
                   "enum" = { "ASC", "DESC" },
                   "description" = "ASC or DESC"
               }
           },
           "responses"={
               "200"={
                   "description"="Retrieve a list of students",
                   "schema"={
                       "type"="object",
                       "properties"={
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
   )
  /
```

Result i got is:- but the count is correct 5 values

```
[
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {}
]
```

Comment: Your issue may be datatype problem, Could you please console.log(typeof yourVariable) to see if it is an array or object?

Comment: i have edited and added some more details!

Comment: @Ajith let me check ! i will reply

Comment: i think am getting the result, but the result is not an array, got error message:- Return value must be of the type array, none returned

Comment: If you have access to the endpoint, then you can format the response message correctly from there

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are json encoding object that has only private/protected properties.
If you var_dump one of the item what is the result?

Comment: let me check that, will reply now!